# Is it possible to specify type of resource in function arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, function, arguments

I must be sure that first argument, passed to my function is FTP_buffer resource.
Is it possible to do it more beauty then

```
<?php
function func($ftp, $smth) {
  if (get_resource_type($ftp) !== 'FTP_buffer') {
    throw new Exception('First argument must be FTP resource!');
  }
}
```

I look for a code like

```
function func (FTP_Buffer_resource $ftp, $smth) {}
```

or something like that, is it possible in PHP?

Comment: see docs http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration here

Comment: Starting with PHP7, you can. See the "type declarations" section of [Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) in the PHP docs. PHP5 has the (similar, but more restricted) concept of "type hints".